# MySQl Procedure INSERT INTO from table and variable

Tags: mysql, insert, procedure

I have a MySQL Procedure that does an insert into a table using a select from another table.
Thus

INSERT INTO my_tbl (fld1, fld2, fld3)
  SELECT fld1, fld2, fld3 FROM tbl_2
  where tbl_2.id=33;

That works fine

However, I now need to insert another field into my_tbl from a value I have in a variable (set from a passed in parameter)

Can someone explain the syntax to mix the insert with fields from the select (which I have already) with the additional field that is a variable in the procedure.

Many thanks

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the variable like you'd use a column or column expression, except if it's a string don't surround it with quotes. If you have, for example, the variable `@idValue`:

```
INSERT INTO my_tbl (fld1, fld2, fld3)
SELECT fld1, fld2, fld3 FROM tbl_2
where tbl_2.id = @idValue;
```

Or if you're updating, say for example you have a variable `@fld2Value`:

```
INSERT INTO my_tbl (fld1, fld2, fld3)
SELECT fld1, @fld2Value, fld3 FROM tbl_2
where tbl_2.id = @idValue;
```

This will insert `tbl2.fld1`, the value of variable `@fld2Value`, and `tbl2.fld3` into `my_tbl`. The number of rows inserted will depend on the number of rows returned by the `SELECT`, and the `@fld2Value` will be the same for each inserted row.